# Pilas a fichero en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de guardar en un fichero los datos de la pila, a lo cual, me crea el archivo de texto pero no me guarda absolutamente nada, es decir está vacío. No sé en dónde podrá encontrarse el error de que no me escriba en el archivo de texto: ¿dónde está el error?
El código funciona perfectamente, lo único que no me ha salido es la parte de escribirlo en un archivo de texto.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <queue>
 #include <fstream>

 using namespace std;

 struct nodo {
     int num;
     struct nodo *sgte;
 };

 typedef nodo *punteroPila;

 void push (punteroPila &p, int val) {
     punteroPila aux;
     aux = new (struct nodo); 
     aux -> num = val;
     aux -> sgte = p;
     p = aux;
 }

 int pop (punteroPila &p){
     int num;
     punteroPila aux;
     aux = p;
     num = aux ->num;
     p = aux -> sgte;
     delete (aux);
     return num;
     }

 void MostrarPila(punteroPila p){
     punteroPila aux;
     aux = p;

     while (aux!= NULL){
         cout << " \t " << aux->num;
         aux = aux = aux -> sgte;
     }

 }

void menu() {
    cout << " \n ****** Menu General *******\n";
    cout << " \n 1. Ingresar datos a la pila";
    cout << " \n 2. Extraer datos de la pila";
    cout << " \n 3. Mostrar datos de la pila";
    cout << " \n 0. Salir \n";
    cout << " \n    Ingrese su opcion: ";               
}

int main() {
    
    string nombreArchivo = "Datos.txt";
    ofstream archivo;
    
    archivo.open(nombreArchivo.c_str(), fstream::out);
    
    punteroPila p = NULL; 
    int datos;
    int opc;
    int numx;
    
    do{
        menu();
        cin >> opc;
        
        switch(opc) {
            
            case 1: 
                for (int j=0; j < 4; j++){
                cout << "\n Ingrese el dato: ";
                cin >> datos;
                push (p,datos);
                cout << "\n Agregado con exito \n"; 
                }
            break;
            
            case 2: 
                numx = pop(p);
                cout << "\n Eliminado con exito n";
            break;
            
            case 3: {
                cout << "\n ***** Datos de la Pila *****\n";
                cout << " \n ";
                if (p!=NULL)
                MostrarPila(p);
                else
                cout << "\n En estos momentos no hay elementos \n";
                break;
            }       
            case 0: {
                cout<<"\n\n\n Programa Finalizado \n";
                exit(1);
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << "\n ";
        system("pause"); 
        
        archivo.close();
    }
    while (opc!=4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, ¿ Podrías remarcar de alguna forma donde haces la escritura al archivo ? No soy capaz de encontrar la forma exacta que estás usando. Aprovecho para recomendarte que consultes lo que es un [mcve]: hay muchas partes de tu código que no son relevantes para la pregunta y distraen, sin aportar nada. Un saludo.

Comment: El archivo está vacío porque no guardas nada en el mismo

Answer (score 1):

Es normal que el archivo no tenga contenido porque no guardas nada en el archivo, lo único que haces es abrirlo:

```
archivo.open(nombreArchivo.c_str(), fstream::out);
```

Y unas líneas después cerrarlo:

```
archivo.close();
```

Sin haber operado con el archivo entre esas dos líneas. Prueba añadir una función que vuelque los datos a archivo:

```
void VolcarDatos(const nodo *&raiz, std::ostream &o) {
    for (nodo *n = raiz; n; n = n->sgte) {
        o << n->num;
    }
}
```

Puedes usar esa función así:

```
VolcarDatos(p, archivo);
```

Como recibe un flujo de salida genérico, también puedes usar esa función para mostrar los datos por consola:

```
VolcarDatos(p, std::cout);
```